# Unable to process request - PLA Update available, while creating the IPA

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, ipa

Error while creating the iOS IPA for submitting it to the app store review.

Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: Unable to process request - PLA Update available
error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found

Answer (score 57, accepted):

PLA Update available

This gives us the idea that there is a new **Program License Agreement** available.

This **Program License Agreement** has to be reviewed and accepted by the Apple developer **Account Holder**.

After this, my issue is resolved.

Go here [Your Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account)

Comment: I hesitate to ask... so how do you or where do you review it and accept it exactly?

Comment: In the Apple developer account, you have to login into the Apple developer account using the account holder's email id and then you can review it.

Comment: I was able to review the agreement by entering the [account page](https://developer.apple.com/account) in Apple Developer website.

Comment: Pity there isn't an API, or robot, or a meta-agreement that agrees to future agreements. I mean, it's not like anybody reads them to know what they are agreeing to.

Answer (score 2):

Visit [Apple Developer Console](https://developer.apple.com/account). And You will able to see new Program License Agreement available. Review and accept the agreement. Come back to Xcode and try again, you will see errors are gone.

Comment: That was the answer, which really helped.